# How to handle null values for the string in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on ASP.NET MVC application. I would like to handle null values (values coming from DB and some of the columns contains null values). If any specific columns contains null values (column is of type string) then we needs to display empty column else the data from that particular column. there is model in which contains those columns and needs to handle the situation using c# and needs to be displayed through view to the end user. I am using MySQL as a DB.

Comment: Exactly what problem are you having? Most UI components handle null values just fine by displaying nothing (equivalent to an empty string)

Comment: Hi @DStanley. Could you please elaborate with an example? In my scenario I am fetching data from the tables in DB in which some of columns are having null value. I am working on asp.net mvc application. where I have created model with all properties but due to null value I am getting error that property cant be applied on null values. I would like to write a code in such a way that if there is any null values then we should display empty columns instead of null else the data for that particular column. Thanks for you kind response. Please feel free if needs more information.

Comment: Some examples of the code that isn't working for you would help us to help you. But as a pointer, have a look at either making the string(s) nullable in your model or using the null coalescing operator to explicitly set a string as empty if the value from the database is null.

Comment: Thanks @John. It worked as your valuable help. I tried to use null coalescing operator as in below comment. Thanks again.

Comment: OldValue = reader.IsDBNull(2) ? null : reader.GetString(2),
 NewValue = reader.IsDBNull(3)? null: reader.GetString(3),